# How do I change the contents of webview component to be vertically aligned using writing-mode in nativescript?

Tags: html, webview, nativescript

Is there any ways that can use css or style to make text contents vertically aligned when working with webview component in nativescript?

I have tried to use class to include a self-made css style, but nothing worked.

.myClass {
 writing-mode:vertical-rl
}

I expect there is a way to be able to change the orientation of texts of webpage in the webview component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change css styles in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048022/change-css-styles-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

As @Manoj mentioned in other post, you can inject CSS after the webpage is loaded.

```
export function onWebViewLoadFinished(args: EventData) {
    const that = this,
        webView = <WebView>args.object,
        jsStr = `var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = "body {writing-mode: vertical-rl !important;}";
                parent.appendChild(style)`;

    if (webView.ios) {
        webView.ios.evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler(jsStr,
            function (
                result,
                error
            ) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error...");
                }
            });
    } else if (webView.android) {
        // Works only on Android 19 and above
        webView.android.evaluateJavascript(
            jsStr,
            null
        );
    }
}
```

P.S. as per MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode), When set for an entire document, it should be set on the root element (html element for HTML documents).